# Get the position after filtering recyclerview

Tags: android, filter, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have a recyclerview and a field for search.
If recycler is unfiltered onClick open the corect details of selected item  but after filtering the recycler open wrong details.
The adapter :

public class AllProductReyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private BaseActivity mContext;
private OnClickItem mInterface;
private  List<Produse> dataList;

public AllProductReyclerAdapter(BaseActivity con, List<Produse> mainCat, OnClickItem _interface) {

    if(con!=null) {
        mContext = con;
        mInterface=_interface;
        dataList=mainCat;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_category_items, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);


    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.tvCatMain.setText("Denumire :"+dataList.get(position).getDenumire());
    holder.tvCode.setText("Code :"+dataList.get(position).getCod());
    holder.tvDeposit.setText("Depozit :"+dataList.get(position).getDepozit());
    holder.tvCant.setText("Cant :"+dataList.get(position).getCant());
    holder.tvDate.setText(dataList.get(position).getPicture());
    if (dataList.get(position).getPicture()!=null)
        Picasso.get().load("http://mysite/test/img/"+dataList.get(position).getProcesare()+" "+dataList.get(position).getCuloare()+".jpg").into(holder.ivItem);

    if (dataList.get(position).getPicture()!=null)
        Picasso.get()
                .load("http://mysite/test/img/"+dataList.get(position).getProcesare()+" "+dataList.get(position).getCuloare()+".jpg")
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .into(holder.ivItem);

      holder.linMain.setTag(dataList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()));

    holder.linMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mInterface.onListItemClick(view.getId(),position);

        }
    });

}



public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public LinearLayout linMain;
    public ImageView ivItem;
    public TextView tvCatMain,tvCode,tvDeposit,tvCant,tvDate;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        tvCatMain = view.findViewById(R.id.tvCatMain);
        ivItem = view.findViewById(R.id.ivItem);
        tvCode = view.findViewById(R.id.tvCode);
        tvDeposit = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDeposit);
        tvCant = view.findViewById(R.id.tvCant);
        tvDate = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        linMain = view.findViewById(R.id.linMain);


    }
}

public void filterList(ArrayList<Produse> filterdNames) {
    this.dataList = filterdNames;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

And this is the fragment :

public class DashboardFragment extends BaseFragment {

```
private RecyclerView rlProductList;
private View ivFilter;
private AllProductReyclerAdapter adapter;
private List<Produse> list=new ArrayList<>();
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setPageTitle("Produse in stoc");
    rlProductList = view.findViewById(R.id.rlProductList);
    ivFilter = view.findViewById(R.id.ivFilter);
    ivFilter.setOnClickListener(this);
    rlProductList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(baseActivity, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    adapter= new AllProductReyclerAdapter(baseActivity,  list, new OnClickItem() {
        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(Object o, int position) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String result = gson.toJson( list.get(position));
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("details",result);
            ProductdetailsFragment fragment=new ProductdetailsFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            displayView(fragment);
        }
    });
    rlProductList.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (getArguments()!=null){
        if (getArguments().getString("search")!=null){

            list.clear();
            list.addAll(Constants.filteredProduct);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }else{
        list.clear();
        list.addAll(Constants.allProduct);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    EditText etFilter = view.findViewById(R.id.etFilter);
    etFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (adapter!=null){
                if (s.toString().length()>0)
                    filter(s.toString());
                else
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    super.onClick(view);
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.ivFilter:
            displayView(new ProductFilterFragment());
            break;

    }
}
private void filter(String names) {
    //new array list that will hold the filtered data
     ArrayList<Produse> filterdNames = new ArrayList<>();

    //looping through existing elements
    for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
        //if the existing elements contains the search input
        if (list.get(i).getPicture()!=null&&list.get(i).getPicture().toLowerCase().contains(names.toLowerCase())) {
            //adding the element to filtered list
            filterdNames.add(list.get(i));
        }
    }

    //calling a method of the adapter class and passing the filtered list
    adapter.filterList(filterdNames);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Me too I met this problem, the solution that I found is not to filter the table by removing the elements. But the filtered articles I set the height to 0. That way I keep the positions.

The code is in kotlin if you can not translate it in java say it to me and I will help you.

**Step 1:**

Add this extension (or translate it in java method):

```
var View.isRemovedHeight: Boolean
get() {
    return this.height == 0
}
set(value) {
    if (value) {
        val params = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0)
        this.layoutParams = params
    } else {
        val params = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        this.layoutParams = params
    }
}
```

**Step 2:**
Add this in your adapter

```
//Filtering implementation
private var textFilter: String = ""
private val filteredItems: ArrayList<Items> = ArrayList()
```

And this:

```
// Filtering implementation
fun filter(text: String) {
    textFilter = text.toLowerCase()

    filteredCustomer.clear()
    filteredCustomer.addAll(items.filter { it.name.toLowerCase().contains(textFilter) || it.address.toLowerCase().contains(textFilter) || it.phone.toLowerCase().contains(textFilter) })
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

fun notifyFilteringDataChanged() {
    filteredCustomer.addAll(items)
    filter(text = textFilter)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

The first method is the logic to filter, the second method is to refresh the recycleriew. The best thing was to do an overide of the method notifyDataSetChanged but we can not because it is final method. So I created a custom notifyDataChanged

**Step 3:**
In the layout xml, put an id in the layout, because we will delete its size and put it to 0

```
//Filtering implementation
val item = items[position]
holder.container.isRemovedHeight = !filteredItems.contains(item)
```

isRemovedHeight is the extension above, but for java you have to call the method translated

In your activity Whenever you want to refresh the data in the recycle view, use the notifyFilteringDataChanged() method so that everything is up to date, like this:

```
adapter.notifyFilteringDataChanged()
```

In you éditent call this method:

```
adapter.filter(s.toString())
```

Sorry for my english I hope it helped you

**Java**

**Step 1:**

```
public boolean removeHeight(View view, boolean isRemoved) {
    if(isRemoved) {
        LayoutParams params = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0);
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
    } else {
        LayoutParams params = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    return isRemoved;
}
```

**Step 2:**

```
private String textFilter = "";
private ArrayList<Item> filteredItems = ArrayList();
```

And:

```
public void filter(String text){
    textFilter = text.toLowerCase();

    filteredCustomer.clear();
    filteredCustomer.addAll(items.stream().filter(i -> i.name.toLowerCase().contains(textFilter)));
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void notifyFilteringDataChanged(){
    filteredCustomer.addAll(items);
    filter(textFilter);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**Step 3:**

```
Item item = items.get(position);
removeHeight(holder.container, !filteredItems.contains(item));
```

And:

```
adapter.notifyFilteringDataChanged();
```

And:

```
adapter.filter(s.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you Mickael for your response. I tried to translate to Java but i dont know how to make. At step 1 you you write an extension in Kotlin , how to make this in Java.

Comment: Look my edit, I have not checked but normally it should work, let me know

Answer (score 0):

You should not set click listener in onBindViewHolder method. Because maybe after data set changes position captured value is wrong.
Best practice is setting click listener inside ViewHolder and get position with getAdapterPosition. Don't forget to compare this value with RecyclerView.No_Position and if not equal then call your callback.